# Lookup column in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience

I've searched around but couldn't find an answer for a simple question:

Is it possible to add a column to a SharePoint list that looks up another column in another list?

Both lists are on the same site, and share and ID in common.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use lookup columns in SharePoint Online.

You can find all the information in below Microsoft documentation:

[Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Note that all colum types are not supported to use as a lookup column, you can find list of all supported and unsupported column types in above documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for helping, I've read the entire page, but it doesn't make sense to me. The target list has a foreign key (integer) that relates to the primary key of the source list. WHERE do I tell Sharepoint THIS COLUMN IS THE FOREIGN KEY?

Comment: Please seem my other question here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288229/how-to-add-a-lookup-column-to-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: Do You have data already in "Entidade_FK" column? Are you adding it manually to list or uploading in bulk?

Comment: You cannot assign existing list column as a foreign key in SharePoint. You can lookup to another column using lookup columns in SharePoint. While you create a lookup column the foreign key and primary key is automatically handled by SharePoint using default unique **ID** column in SharePoint.

Comment: For example in your case: when creating a new list item in Diario list, if you select "DEF" in newly created lookup column then SharePoint will store the unique **ID** of DEF in Diario list (backend) but it will show "DEF" value in list view.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the SharePoint list, it is not the same as the database table, there is no concept of primary key, foreign key in SharePoint.SharePoint is one of the leading portal technologies, not a relational database. The lookup column can only select the value from the source list column's value. This is similar to the foreign key, but there can be multiple columns in a list at the same time as the source list column.