# How to add a lookup column to a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I have 2 Sharepoint Lists:

`Entidades`:

```
Entidade_ID | Nome
1           | ABC
2           | DEF
```

And `Diario`:

```
Diario_ID   |  Entidade_FK
1           |  2
2           |  1
3           |  2
```

I want to add a lookup column to `Diario` to get the Nome of `Entidades`.

In SharePoint, this is what I'm doing:

[image]

Get information from "Entidades" and return NomeCurto (the name).

**But where does the Foreign Key go!?**

This operation adds a column to Entidades but an empty one, because the foreign key isn't anywhere!

I hope this makes sense and someone can help, I've read the whole documentation, but it isn't there either.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I tried also the following setting:

[image]

[image]

But this also returns an empty column.

I think it is because the target list has other foreign keys which now contain little red icons...

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple demo for you.

**First this is the list Entidades:**
[image]
**Then create the list Diario:**
[image]
Then create a lookup column Entidade_FK, make sure **Get information form** Entidade, **the selected column** is Entidade_ID and **check the Nome**:

[image]

**At last:**
[image]
If you don't want to display the column Entidade_FK, you can choose to hide it, just go to **List Settings>View>Your current view**,and **uncheck the Entidade_FK column**:
[image]
[image]
**Finally:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get empty columns... I don't understand how Sharepoint "discovers" which column to use as foreign key. Here's a link with sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzIXgedas0AxpzV6oUixjLk5jSsfGvY7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use a lookup column in SharePoint, you don't need to build a lookup key manually. SharePoint takes care of that.

You just select which list you want to use as the source for the lookup column and which column of that list should be used for the visible data drop-down. SharePoint then takes care of the lookup architecture and internally uses the built-in list item ID as the key.

So, just select which column you want as the main lookup value, and, if you want, also add other columns from the lookup list, to supplement the value that was looked up.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you, please see my edited question above.